# How to stop the timer and move to next scene when puzzle is solved

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I created a jigsaw in action script and kept it a separate class. In the project i linked the code and i added a timer to the scene so that the player have to solve the puzzle within the time specified. Now what i want is that if the player solved the puzzle correctly the timer will stop and go to next scene.

this is the puzzle.as

```
var xpos:Array=new Array();
var ypos:Array=new Array();
var numDone,i:int;
var numPieces:int=3;
var dif:int=25; //how close do they have to drag the piece
var sound:Sound=new Sound();
function playSound(file:String): void {
    //var sound:Sound=new Sound();
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest(file);
    sound.load(req);
    sound.play();
} //playSound

function scramble(): void {
    for(i=0;i<numPieces;i++){
        this["piece"+i].x=Math.random()*300;
        this["piece"+i].y=Math.random()*500; 
        this["piece"+i].alpha=.8;
    } //for each piece
    numDone=0;
    txtMessage.text="Drag the pieces to solve the puzzle";
    sound.close();
} //scramble
function init(): void {
    for(i=0;i<numPieces;i++){
        xpos[i]=this["piece"+i].x;
        ypos[i]=this["piece"+i].y;
        this["piece"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginMove);
        this["piece"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endMove);
    } //for each piece
    txtMessage.text="Drag the pieces to solve the puzzle";
} //init
function beginMove(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if(e.target.alpha<1)
     e.target.startDrag();
} //beginMove
function endMove(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if(e.target.alpha<1) {
        e.target.stopDrag();
        //figure out which piece it is
        var piece:int=0;
        while(e.target!=this["piece"+piece]){
            piece++;
        } //
        var curX:int=this["piece"+piece].x;
        var curY:int=this["piece"+piece].y;
        if(curX<=xpos[piece]+dif && curX>=xpos[piece]-dif && 
            curY<=ypos[piece]+dif && curY>=ypos[piece]-dif) { //close enough
            this["piece"+piece].x=xpos[piece];
            this["piece"+piece].y=ypos[piece];
            this["piece"+piece].alpha=1;
            numDone++;
            if(numDone>=numPieces) gameOver();
            else playSound("http://www.zebra0.com/langResource/ok.mp3");
        } //in position
    } //not already done
}//endMove
function gameOver(): void {
    txtMessage.text="You did it!";
    playSound("http://www.zebra0.com/langResource/win.mp3");
    gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
} //gameOver

function scrambleHandler(e:MouseEvent): void {
    scramble();
} //clickHandler

btnScramble.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,scrambleHandler);
function solve(e:MouseEvent): void {
    for(i=0;i<numPieces;i++) {
        this["piece"+i].x=xpos[i];
        this["piece"+i].y=ypos[i];
        this["piece"+i].alpha=1;
    } //for each piece
} //solve
```

the code for linking the puzzle.as to the project. i kept in a layer called 'ActionScript'

```
include "Puzzle.as"
numPieces=20;
init();
scramble();
stop();
```

timer code i kept in a layer called 'action'

```
var nCount:Number = 90;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, nCount);

timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    nCount--;
    timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
}
function onComplete(e: TimerEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(35);
}
```

if any one have an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: If all this code is on the same timeline just do `myTimer.reset();` in your game over function

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis No it's not on the same timeline. Puzzle.as is a separate file(actionscript class)

Comment: It's a separate file, but since you're using `include` it's the same scope as wherever you used include.  (include just takes the code from the file and inserts it where you used include as if you'd typed it all there).  It's not clear if all the code blocks you've shared are on the same timeline or not